# Get rid of alt text for html on hover

Tags: html, image, hover, title, alt

I'm trying to create a page of images and I've manged to make them fancy by adding captions that only appear when each image is hovered over. But now I'm having problems with **duplicate captions** as it seems that a white caption box also appears wherever my mouse is when the images are hovered over. I think someone said this is the alt text or something but I'm not sure. In any case, I want to remove it so I don't have it interfering with my other fancier hover caption. I can't attach an image but hopefully you understand my problem.

The code I used is below:

```
<style type="text/css">
  a.hovertext {
    position: relative;
    width: 320px;
    text-decoration: none !important;
text-align: center;
  }
 a.hovertext:after {
    content: attr(title);
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 0em 0px;
    width: 320px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    text-decoration: none !important;
    color: #fff;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: 0.5s;
    -o-transition: 0.5s;
    -ms-transition: 0.5s;
      }
  a.hovertext:hover:after, a.hovertext:focus:after {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
</style>
<div class="noborderdv" style="clear: both; text-align: left;">
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="5" style="width: 500px;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td align="center" valign="center"><a class="hovertext" href="https://www.blogger.com/blogger.g?blogID=6870619294109194114#" title="Sandwich"><img alt="" border="0" src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-nHv87zBke7I/U5fwCcRoe2I/AAAAAAAAAgs/BupH3BsNoj4/s1600/DSCN6778.JPG" height="258" width="320" /></a>
</td>
<td align="center" valign="center"><a class="hovertext" href="https://www.blogger.com/blogger.g?blogID=6870619294109194114#" title="Bitte Sandwich"><img alt="" border="0" src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-PFpW_AZbbFg/U5fwIhjwXZI/AAAAAAAAAhM/OMQZpy8wx2E/s1600/DSCN6866c.JPG" height="240" width="320" /></a>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</div>
```

How can I get rid of the white box caption as this is particularly annoying when I have longer captions.

Comment: It’s not the `alt` of the image, it’s the `title` of the link – it is default browser behavior to show the content of that as a little tooltip when you over an element with a `title` attribute set. Use another attribute, f.e. an HTML5 custom data attribute like `data-title`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this:

```
<style type="text/css">
  a.hovertext:after { content: attr(title); }
</style>
<a title="Sandwitch">...</a>
```

with this:

```
<style type="text/css">
  a.hovertext:after { content: attr(data-title); }
</style>
<a data-title="Sandwitch">...</a>
```

HTML5 `data-*` attributes will allow you to insert additional data into the markup without triggering the default user-agent caption.

Comment: That worked thanks! Do you by chance know how to make the images enlarge when clicked on. This happens automatically for all of my other pages with images. But for these images, when I click on them it redirects to my personal blogger settings page (even the public would redirect there..just with no access). Not sure where in the code, this would occur.

Comment: I am no blogger expert but it looks that you have bad URLs for both the link and the image tag.
Your image links contain a sequence `/s1600/`. This is how blogger resizes the requested images. Change this value in all your image tags to `/s320/` to match the `width="320"` parameter. Use the original link with the `/s1600/` sequence in your link tags.
This will make blogger display small, optimized images as thumbnails and large ones only when an image is clicked.